# I deleted a file using the command 'dbutils.fs.rm' in Databricks File Storage. Is there a way to retrieve that back?

Tags: python, mysql, database, azure

I used this command and accidentally deleted a file from DBFS. Is there a way to retrieve that file as it is, without changes in the script?

```
%python dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sql/global_franchise/liverpool/location/store_hierarchy/franchise_store_hierarchy_merge_into_ndp.sql", True)
```

Comment: don't you have backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no possible way to restore the deleted files from DBFS. Only possible way is to have a backup and restore it to the DBFS.

Please go through the [DBFS document](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html) for more details.